# Store XML data as an array, Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xml, parsing, struct

So I am working on a project which will allow users to do multiple different quizzes.

My XML, which is hosted online, is of the following format:

```
<questions>
    <question>
        <clue> sample clue 1 </clue>
        <correct_answer>2</correct_answer>
        <enumeration>1</enumeration>
        <info> sample info 1 </info>
        <location_clue>Sample locationClue (5,5)</location_clue>
        <option_a>Ans1</option_a>
        <option_b>Ans2</option_b>
        <option_c>Ans3</option_c>
    </question>
    <question>
        <clue> sample clue 2 </clue>
        <correct_answer>3</correct_answer>
        <enumeration>2</enumeration>
        <info> sample info 2 </info>
        <location_clue>Sample locationClue (4,2)</location_clue>
        <option_a>Ans1</option_a>
        <option_b>Ans2</option_b>
        <option_c>Ans3</option_c>
    </question>
</questions>
```

my parser initiation looks like this:

```
if let urlString = URL(string: "realURL goes here.xml -- This has an actual url in my code obviously.")
    {

        if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: urlString)
        {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
```

parserDidStartElement:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:])
{
    thisName = elementName

    if thisName == "hunt"
    {

    }
}
```

ParserFoundCharacter:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)


    if data.count != 0
    {
        switch thisName
        {
        case "clue": questionClue = data
            break
        case "info": questionInfo = data
            break
        case "location_clue": locationClue = data
            break
        case "option_a": questionAnswerA = data
            break
        case "option_b": questionAnswerB = data
            break
        case "option_c": questionAnswerC = data
        default:
            break

        }
    }

}
```

This is the HuntDetail.swift class which creates a scruct named QUIZ, inside of this scruct there are currently 4 variables, question, answerA, answerB and answerC:

```
import Foundation

struct QUIZ {
    var question = ""
    var answerA = ""
    var answerB = ""
    var answerC = ""
}
```

Essentially the app will allow users to take multi-choice quizzes. When answers are selected a progress bar at the top of the interface will indicate their progress through the current quiz.

I was wondering if it would be possible to store the value of: clue,info,location_clue,option_a,b,c... inside of an array, from the array I will start to formulate the actual quiz functionality.

As it stands right now, the application will only display the last element of the data previously mentioned.

I know this is long and probably hard to understand what I'm trying to do but if anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated. It should also be noted that, yes, I am fairly new to Swift and iOS development as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this fairly easily, although I haven't used XMLParser in a while.

**Note:** In my code below I have renamed your `QUIZ` to `Question` as the struct represents a single question, not a whole quiz (list of questions)

So you want an empty array to each item to as you parse it:

```
var quiz = [Question]() // quiz is a list of questions.
```

Then you want to track the current question you are working on

```
var currentQuestion: Question?
```

So then each time you start and end a Question element, you know you have finished parsing a single question, so add it to the list.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {


    if elementName == "Question" {
        currentQuestion = Question()
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

     if elementName == "Question", let question = currentQuestion {
          quiz.append(question)
     }
}
```

So you are just parsing the XML document top to bottom. Once you come upon a opening Question element, create a question object, fill the rest in and then when you encounter a closing question element, add the current question to the list.

By the end of the document your quiz variable should contain all of the questions in the document.

EDIT:

So I had to make a few changes, the foundCharacters can come in parts so we need to keep track of it.

Here is a working playground which returns 2 questions (based on your sample XML above). Answer C is always blank, It looks like this is because of a newline char and the trim is cutting of the text, you may need to remove newlines and then just trim whitespace but this code will give you a good start.

```
import Foundation

let xmlData = """
<questions>
    <question>
        <clue> sample clue 1 </clue>
        <correct_answer>2</correct_answer>
        <enumeration>1</enumeration>
        <info> sample info 1 </info>
        <location_clue>Sample locationClue (5,5)</location_clue>
        <option_a>Ans1</option_a>
        <option_b>Ans2</option_b>
        <option_c>Ans3</option_c>
    </question>
    <question>
        <clue> sample clue 2 </clue>
        <correct_answer>3</correct_answer>
        <enumeration>2</enumeration>
        <info> sample info 2 </info>
        <location_clue>Sample locationClue (4,2)</location_clue>
        <option_a>Ans1</option_a>
        <option_b>Ans2</option_b>
        <option_c>Ans3</option_c>
    </question>
</questions>
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Question {
    var question: String?
    var clue: String?
    var info: String?
    var locationClue: String?
    var answerA: String?
    var answerB: String?
    var answerC: String?
}

class MySuperXMLParser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    private let parser: XMLParser
    private var quiz = [Question]()
    private var currentQuestion: Question?
    private var currentElement: String?
    private var foundCharacters = ""

    init(data: Data) {
        parser = XMLParser(data: data)
        super.init()
        parser.delegate = self
    }

    func parse() -> [Question] {
        parser.parse()
        return quiz
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

        if elementName == "question" {
            currentQuestion = Question()
        }

        print("Started element: \(elementName)")
        currentElement = elementName
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        print("found characters: \(string)")
        foundCharacters += string
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        print("ended element: \(elementName), text = \(foundCharacters)")

        let text = foundCharacters.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

        switch currentElement
        {
        case "clue":
            currentQuestion?.clue = text
            break
        case "info":
            currentQuestion?.info = text
            break
        case "location_clue":
            currentQuestion?.locationClue = text
            break
        case "option_a":
            currentQuestion?.answerA = text
            break
        case "option_b":
            currentQuestion?.answerB = text
            break
        case "option_c": currentQuestion?.answerC = text
        default:
            break
        }

        foundCharacters = ""

        if elementName == "question", let question = currentQuestion {
            print("adding question: \(question)")
            quiz.append(question)
        }
    }
}

let parser = MySuperXMLParser(data: xmlData)
let quiz = parser.parse()
print(quiz.count, quiz)
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for the pretty detailed response. When I add your code everything seems to be working fine, however when I try and print the quiz variable you created with the print(quiz), the only output i receive is []. any help there? sorry about this

Comment: Hey sorry I left the office just after posting. you may need to step through the code or add some print statements in so that you can see what is going on with it. this should work, I'll see if i can put an example together

Comment: I have updated it with a working example and some more explanation. A guide which may help understanding: http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/24/xml-parsing-swift/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply again and sorry about this delayed response. I'm having some trouble in regards to the init.super() line, I am just new to this so I'm unsure if I'm actually doing it in the correct place, could I add you to a discord server or something for some help? No worries if not just need a bit of a hand

Comment: I'm not on discord mate, but you should have a full solution there. Can add you on a chat on here if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using an external library, you can try [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper).

Just use the following model classes:

```
class Questions: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var questions: [Question]?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        questions <- map["question"]
    }
}

class Question: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var clue: String?
    var correct_answer: Int?
    var enumeration: Int?
    var info: String?
    var location_clue: String?
    var option_a: String?
    var option_b: String?
    var option_c: String?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        clue <- map["clue"]
        correct_answer <- map["correct_answer"]
        enumeration <- map["enumeration"]
        info <- map["info"]
        location_clue <- map["location_clue"]
        option_a <- map["option_a"]
        option_b <- map["option_b"]
        option_c <- map["option_c"]
    }
}
```

And map your XML by calling `map(XMLString:)` function in `XMLMapper`:

```
let object = XMLMapper<Questions>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
print(object?.questions?.first?.clue ?? "nil")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting value nil

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia could you be more specific, please? At which point do you get `nil` value? If you are facing an issue, please open a new issue on XMLMapper's github repo.